# Selenium/Specflow/C# - Make a base64 image open in another tab

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, base64, specflow

I am currently using Specflow and Selenium to automate my QA. After each test, it generates an Extent Report and, when some error occurs during the test, it takes a screenshot and puts the link to it right below the message, but when I click at the link, it doesn't do anything. So I have to right-click on it, and open it at a new tab. The image is coded on C# using its base64 format. Can anyone tell me how I can make the screenshot open at a new tab with a normal left-click?

Here's my code:

```
else if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError != null)
            {
                if (stepType == "Given")
                {
                    var gDriverHook = AssertDriverHook(DriverHook);
                    CapturaTela.ErrorScreenshot(AssertDriverHook(gDriverHook));
                    _scenario.CreateNode<Given>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message);
                    _scenario.CreateNode<Given>("Detalhes:").Fail("<a href =" + "data:image/jpeg;base64," + CapturaTela.ErrorScreenshot(gDriverHook) + ">" + "Clique Aqui para ver a Imagem" + "</a>");
                }

                else if (stepType == "When")
                {
                    var gDriverHook = AssertDriverHook(DriverHook);
                    CapturaTela.ErrorScreenshot(AssertDriverHook(gDriverHook));
                    _scenario.CreateNode<When>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message + " \n \n <a href =" + "data:image/jpeg;base64," + CapturaTela.ErrorScreenshot(gDriverHook) + ">" + "Clique Aqui para ver a Imagem" + "</a>");
                }

                else if (stepType == "Then")
                {
                    var gDriverHook = AssertDriverHook(DriverHook);
                    CapturaTela.ErrorScreenshot(AssertDriverHook(gDriverHook));
                    _scenario.CreateNode<Then>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message);
                    _scenario.CreateNode<Then>("Detalhes:").Fail("<a href =" + "data:image/jpeg;base64," + CapturaTela.ErrorScreenshot(gDriverHook) + ">" + "Clique Aqui para ver a Imagem" + "</a>");
                }
            }
```

And Here's where my Screenshot method is:

```
       public static string ErrorScreenshot(IWebDriver pDriver)
    {
        ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = pDriver as ITakesScreenshot;
        Screenshot screenshot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
        string base64 = screenshot.AsBase64EncodedString.Replace("\"\"", "");

        string ErrDirectory = "C:/Screenshot/err/";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(ErrDirectory);
        ErrDirectory = ErrDirectory + "Err_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss");
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(ErrDirectory, ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);

        return base64;
    }
```

Here's the link I'm trying to click:

[image: Here's the link I'm trying to click]